# If $f(z_n)=0$ and $z_n\longrightarrow a$ then $f\equiv 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

Is the following proposition true or false?

> Let $f:\overline{D(0,1)}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function on $D(0,1)$ and continuous on $\overline{D(0,1)}$ such that there is a sequence $z_n\in D(0,1)$ with $z_n\longrightarrow a$ , $f(z_n)=0$ , $|a|=1$ then $f\equiv0$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i think it is not true, since $a \notin  D$

Comment: The continuity plays a role, otherwise $\sin(1/z-1)$ shows it is false.

Comment: ^^ I mean $\sin(1/(z-1))$

Comment: Some more remarks. We must have $f(a) = 0$ by continuity. If the function takes real values on all of the boundary of the ball, the Schwarz reflection principle allows it to be extended which makes the identity theorem apply.

Comment: I just found this MO post that implies even constructing functions that are analytic on the open ball and continuous on the closed ball but don't analytically extend is a non trivial task, even without the assumption to do with the zeroes http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10831/example-of-continuous-function-that-is-analytic-on-the-interior-but-cannot-be-an

Answer (score 1):

$f(z) = (z-1) B(z)$ is such a function, if $B$ is a Blaschke product with zeros accumulating at $a=1$, say
$$
B(z) = \prod \frac{1-2^{-n}-z}{1-(1-2^{-n})z} .
$$
This follows from the following facts about Blaschke products: (1) $B$ has a holomorphic continuation through any arc that has a neighborhood that is free of zeros (so this $B$ is holomorphic away from $a=1$); (2) $|B|<1$ on $D$.